# How to draw multi images of the same object onto a single canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, laravel-5

I want to draw onto a canvas multi times with the same image, in other words i want to apply code that will when i click on the canvas area produces an image and when i click again somewhere else it produces another image and so on.

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

But when trying to draw again it instead replaces the previous image that was drawn and then draws the new image. instead of keeping the previous drawn image on the canvas.

```
function drawAll(){
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width, imageObj.height,0, 0, 700, 618);

    if(coordinates.length > 0){
    coordinates.map((coord, key) =>{
    context.beginPath();

    context.moveTo(coord.startX, coord.startY);

    context.lineTo(coord.toX,coord.toY);

    context.strokeStyle="rgb(226, 104, 36)";
    context.lineWidth=2;
    context.stroke();                   
        });
    }

    if(entry){
        context.drawImage(imageObjBall, entry.posX-8, entry.posY-8, 16, 16);
    }
}
```

> EDIT: Hey sorry forgot to insert this bit down here

```
function handleClick(e){
    if(!isDrawing && prize_id != null){
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    mouseX = pos.x;
    mouseY = pos.y;

    $x_id=`#cor_x_${prize_id}`;
    $y_id=`#cor_y_${prize_id}`;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 618);

    context.drawImage(imageObjBall, mouseX-8, mouseY-8, 16, 16);

    entry={posX:mouseX,posY:mouseY};

    $($x_id).text(mouseX);
    $($y_id).text(mouseY);        
    drawAll();
    }
}
```

> NOTE: This is in laravel 5, there is more code outside of this but i
>   felt this was the necessary snipped needed for you to be able to help
>   me but if you need more please ask me to edit some more code into this
>   post

Comment: Your question in short: "How to add additional images to an existing canvas object?", right?

Comment: yes but the same object, not to create an entirely new one. so multi "imageObjBall"s

Answer (score 1):

To draw multiple images onto the canvas using a single image object, create the image object via `new Image()` and set the `src` property accordingly.

Alternatively, you can also write an `<img src="">` tag in the HTML code and get a reference to it via `document.querySelector`.

There is one important thing to consider: Before you call `drawImage`, you have to make sure the image is loaded, even when there are no load times (eg. localhost or data-url).

In my example, I solved this by not starting the animation immediately. Instead, the requestAnimationFrame loop is started in the image onload event.

```js
var R = Math.random
var a = document.getElementById("a")
var W = a.width = 400
var H = a.height = 300
var c = a.getContext("2d")

var img = new Image()
img.src = 'https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f60d.png'


function loop() {
  var rndX = (R()*W)|0
  var rndY = (R()*H)|0
  c.drawImage(img, rndX, rndY)
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}

img.onload=function() {
  loop()
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
```

Comment: your code is nice :). However im not sure how to implement it with mine, i did create the image beforehand using 
                               var imageObjBall = new Image();
                               imageObjBall.src='/images/golfball_small.png';
I did not however use a loop. How would i emulate this with onclick?